# Objective-c equivalent code

Tags: objective-c

What would be the equivalent of this code in Objective-C?

```
array2[i]=array[i].split("!");
```

Comment: What does array2[i]=array[i].split("!"); do?

Comment: At least tell us which language is that.

Comment: It looks like Python. Looks so much more concise than Objective C, doesn't it?

Comment: @Vladimir: Python probably wouldn't have the final semicolon.

Comment: @Josh: a semicolon is not necessary, but it is legal.

Comment: @Vladimir: Right, that's why I said "probably".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) documentation. It may look something like this:

```
[array2 replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a few change and got it worked: 

[rows insertObject:[[sections objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"] atIndex:i];

Answer (score 0):

Here is an objective-c example of the split function

```
    NSString *myString = @"This is a test";
    NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    // myWords is now: [@"This", @"is", @"a", @"test"]
```

This is a link to a decent reference for the function.

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Strings/split.html